# CMake not finding boost_thread and boost_system

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, cgal

I saw at least 5 questions with the same title as this question. Each of them had a different answer that worked for the OP but not for me, so I am sorry to repeat the question.

I am trying to install CGAL using http://www.cgal.org/download/windows.html on windows 8.

Steps that I have done:

1)Install "boost_1_55_0-msvc-9.0-64.exe" in "C:\dev\libboost_1_55_0" directory

2)Add two below system enviroment variables:
BOOST_LIBRARYDIR=C:\dev\libboost_1_55_0\lib64-msvc-9.0
BOOST_INCLUDEDIR=C:\dev\libboost_1_55_0

3)I add to my PATH environment variable "C:\dev\libboost_1_55_0\lib64-msvc-9.0"

4)I install CGAL in "C:\dev\CGAL-4.0"

5)I install Cmake

6)Open CMake-GUI and set C:\dev\CGAL-4.0 for source and C:\dev\CGAL-4.0\build as 
binaries

7)I click on Configure and choose "Visual Studio 12 2013"

When I click configure, I get the following output:

```
== Setting paths ==
Build CGAL from release in directory CGAL-4.0
Packagenames: CGAL-4.0
== Setting paths (DONE) ==

== Generate version files ==
CGAL_MAJOR_VERSION=4
CGAL_MINOR_VERSION=6
CGAL_BUGFIX_VERSION=1
CGAL_SONAME_VERSION=11
CGAL_SOVERSION     =11.0.0
CGAL_REFERENCE_CACHE_DIR=
Building shared libraries
Targetting Visual Studio 12 2013
Target build enviroment supports auto-linking
Using VC12 compiler.
Generator uses intermediate configuration directory: $(Configuration)
USING CMake version: 3.2.3
System: Windows
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:438 (if):
  Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
  keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
  details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
  warning.

  Quoted variables like "MSVC" will no longer be dereferenced when the policy
  is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior will be used.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

== Generate version files (DONE) ==

== Set up flags ==
Build type: Release
USING CXXFLAGS = ' /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /fp:strict /fp:except- /wd4503 /bigobj /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG'
USING LDFLAGS = ' /machine:X86 /INCREMENTAL:NO'
== Set up flags (DONE) ==

== Detect external libraries ==
External libraries supported: GMP;MPFR;ZLIB;OpenGL;LEDA;MPFI;RS;RS3;OpenNL;Eigen3;BLAS;LAPACK;QGLViewer;ESBTL;Coin3D;NTL;IPE
Preconfiguring library: GMP ...
GMP has been preconfigured:
  UseGMP-file:      
  GMP include:      C:/dev/CGAL-4.0/auxiliary/gmp/include
  GMP libraries:    C:/dev/CGAL-4.0/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libgmp-10.lib
  GMP definitions:  
USING GMP_VERSION = '5.0.1'
Preconfiguring library: MPFR ...
MPFR has been preconfigured:
  UseMPFR-file:      
  MPFR include:      C:/dev/CGAL-4.0/auxiliary/gmp/include
  MPFR libraries:    C:/dev/CGAL-4.0/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libmpfr-4.lib
  MPFR definitions:  
USING MPFR_VERSION = '3.0.0'
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1182 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.55.0

  Boost include path: C:/dev/libboost_1_55_0

  Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

          boost_thread
          boost_system

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupBoost.cmake:6 (find_package)
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupDependencies.cmake:85 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:640 (include)


Boost include:     C:/dev/libboost_1_55_0
Boost libraries:   
Boost definitions: 
USING BOOST_VERSION = '1.55.0'
== Detect external libraries (DONE) ==

== Write compiler_config.h ==
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:670 (if):
  Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
  keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
  details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
  warning.

  Quoted variables like "CGAL_CFG_BOOST_VARIANT_SWAP_BUG" will no longer be
  dereferenced when the policy is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set
  the OLD behavior will be used.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

== Write compiler_config.h (DONE) ==

== Generating build files ==
Configuring libCGAL
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
libCGAL is configured
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Core' detected
Configuring libCGAL_Core
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
libCGAL_Core is configured
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_ImageIO' detected
Configuring libCGAL_ImageIO
Could NOT find ZLIB (missing:  ZLIB_LIBRARY ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR) 
OpenGL include:     
OpenGL libraries:   glu32;opengl32
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
libCGAL_ImageIO is configured
NOTICE: libCGAL_ImageIO needs ZLib to read compressed files. That feature will not be activated.
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Qt3' detected
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Qt4' detected
Sources for CGAL component libraries 'CGAL_Core;CGAL_ImageIO;CGAL_Qt3;CGAL_Qt4' detected
== Generating build files (DONE) ==

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/dev/CGAL-4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/dev/CGAL-4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

And I encounter "error in configuration process,project files may invalid" message.What is the problem?

Comment: You should specify what you have already tried

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you [build](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries) the libraries. `System` and `Thread` have to be built. Therefore simply including the header files won't work. Use the `b2` script/batch in order to build with static or shared libraries.

Comment: The boost_...exe installers are about precompiled libraries, so I am not sure that this is a good answer.

Comment: The webpage points you to both. It depends on which one has been downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

You combine boost_1_55_0-msvc-9.0-64.exe  which is as the name says for msvc-9.0 with Visual Studio 12 2013, so you will not have the right lib and dll files.

As a side remark, or question: why do you use CGAL 4.0 ? This is more than 3 years old code.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly should I do?